# Percentage of Random Calls to Different Command in Text File

Tags: java, multithreading, random

This is my Config File(Test.txt)

```
CommandA   75%
CommandB   15%
CommandC   10%
```

I wrote a multithreading program in which I am reading the files line by line but not sure how should I do the above question in which this much percentage(75%) of random calls go to CommandA, and this much percentage(15%) of random calls go to CommandB and same with CommandC.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            for (int i = 1; i <= threadSize; i++) {
                new Thread(new ThreadTask(i)).start();
            }
        }

class ThreadTask implements Runnable {

        public synchronized void run() {
            BufferedReader br = null;

            try {
                String line;

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Test.txt"));

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] s = line.split("\\s+");
                    for (String split : s) {
                    System.out.println(split);
                }
            }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null)br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a random number 1-100. If the number is 1-75 do command A, 76-90 do command B, 91-100 do command C.

EDITED for comment:

There are two ways I would consider doing this. If you only have the three commands (A, B, C) then you can do a simple:

```
    int[] commandPercentages = {75, 15, 10};        
    int randomNumber = 90;

    if((randomNumber -= commandPercentages[0]) < 0) {
        //Execute Command A
    }
    else if((randomNumber -= commandPercentages[1]) < 0) {
        //Execute Command B
    }
    else {
        //Execute Command C
    }
```

if you have a lot of complicated commands you can set up the commands like so:

```
private abstract class Command {
    int m_percentage;       
    Command(int percentage) {
        m_percentage = percentage;
    }       
    int getPercentage() {
        return m_percentage;
    }
    abstract void executeCommand();
};

private class CommandA extends Command {        
    CommandA(int percentage) {
        super(percentage);
    }
    @Override
    public void executeCommand() {
        //Execute Command A
    }       
}

private class CommandB extends Command {        
    CommandB(int percentage) {
        super(percentage);
    }
    @Override
    public void executeCommand() {
        //Execute Command B
    }

}
```

and then choose the command like so:

```
    Command[] commands = null;  
    int randomNumber = 90;

    commands[0] = new CommandA(75);
    commands[1] = new CommandB(25);

    for(Command c: commands) {
        randomNumber -= c.getPercentage();
        if(randomNumber < 0) {
            c.executeCommand();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So Suppose if I am generating random number between 1 and 100. 
And if the number is between 1 and 75, I will execute CommandA, so that means it will execute CommandA 75% of the time? 
And if the number is between 76 and 90, I will execute CommandB, so that means it will execute CommandB 15% of the time? 
And same with CommandC?

Comment: How can I make this more configurable in the code as the percentage number will keep on changing in the config file, so based on the percentage in the config file how can I make this configurable for all the situations. But for this case I can hardcode the conditions but in general case how can I make this configurable. Any code snippet will be appreciated.

Comment: I will give you the more general form of the algorithm suggested above. Note, by Pn, I mean probability for Command N. If the number is 1 to Pa do command A, (Pa + 1) to (Pa + Pb) do command B, (Pa+Pb+1) to (Pa + Pb + Pc) do command C. Hope that helps. You can extend the pattern to more commands.

Comment: I've given two possible ways to implement this Raihan.

Comment: Thanks thagorn but in my config file there can be multiple command names(not limited to 3) and percentage number can also be changed, So the example that you gave me will work for extreme cases?

Comment: AS long as you know about all the commands before the config file this should work for any case. If the config file is when you first learn about the command I would need to see a more specific example.

Comment: In my case the problem is- Config File can change anytime so my code needs to behave according to my Config File. So there can be any number of Command Names (CommandA - CommandN) not limited to three and having any percentage number infront of the Command names.

Comment: Okay yes but that could mean two things. Either 1: there are a set N Commands (A... N) and the config file can give percentages to any or all of them or 2: the config file creates N completely new commands. In example 1, this code will work fine. In example 2 I need to know more about the commands.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the Config File, from that you will be having clear picture.

Comment: @RaihanJamal This is homework, we don't want to give you the full answer. You have been supplied a solution to a specific case of the problem, now you should try to understand what the solution is doing and generalize it.

Comment: @Konstantin Actually this is not a homework but I have marked this as an homework, I am working on some projects in a company as I joined recently here, so that is the reason I was confused about the logic, I need to expand this solution as the question that I have posted is very small so that I can understand what has to be done.

Comment: It looks like that config file should work fine with what I've given. Give it a go and come back if you can't get it to work.

Comment: @thagorn Can you explain me your first Logic in example 1, So I can generate any random number and subtract with the Percentage and if it is less than 0 then execute the command?